# Add a static route in network manager if on certain wifi network

Tags: networkmanager, route

I can't add a static route to my Xfinity router, or I'd do this there.

I have two networks at home and I need to add a static route to my laptop when I need to connect to a computer or the other network. Is there a way to add the static route automatically only when I connect to my home wifi network?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the name of the connection profile in question by looking at the output of `nmcli connection`.

Then, modify the profile accordingly, like `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE_NAME" +ipv4.routes "192.268.7.0/24 192.168.7.1"`

Look at the result: `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE_NAME"`.

Finally, reactive the profile with `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE_NAME"`.

Check the result with `ip route show`

You can also use any other NetworkManager client, like the GUI `nm-connection`editor`.